# Splash screen not changing after upgrading to newer version

Tags: ios, splash-screen

This problem has been discussed on SO already but nothing seems to help me. Users of the app that I'm working on up install new version, which has a new splash screen and that new screen is not displayed. The old one is displayed on launch. I tried changing name of the splash screen file, but the app keeps showing the old screen. Any ideas, guys?

Comment: i noticed a bug like this, but this rarly happens, or it happens all the time?

Comment: @DeyaEldeen it seems to be happening all the time

Comment: clean, and force clean before building, it looks like you just replaced the same file with the same name ?

Comment: no, I even changed the name of the file. it still keeps loading the old one

Comment: @AndreyChernukha can you try by deleting the old image? Or Before can you search in project navigator that whether it is being used at some other place ?

Comment: @SatishMavani the old image is of course deleted. It's not in the project for sure

Comment: @AndreyChernukha if you found it out, pls tell us

Comment: @incmiko I provided an answer. Please take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by starting using xib file for launch instead of an image.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and it's *ridiculous*... The only one way was to solve this:

- delete your app from your device (even clean your project: command+shift+k)
- **reboot your device** :D :D :D funny, isn't it?
- reinstall your app from xcode

and voila ... new splash screen is on your iPhone

Comment: Deleting app works, but it's not a solution. I can't tell my users to delete the app before installing new version. I need to go without deleting somehow